# Php problem, trying to change multiple numbers in a file. Str_replace replaces everything till max

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm trying to make script that increases all grades in textfile by +1. Like 0 -> 1, 1 -> 2 etc. Grade 5 should not be increased at all, as it's best from 0-5.

Problem is that my script gives following output:
New grades:

```
5
5
5
5
5
5
```

When it should give:
New grades:

```
1
5
2
4
3
5
```

It seems that `str_replace()` searches for 0, turns it to 1, then finds that 1 again and replaces it with 2.... and in the end all of grades are 5. Is there way to do this only once for each grade? I tried `preg_replace()`, but it gives error:

> PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Here's my script:

```
<?php
$file = 'grades.txt';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($file);

$fh = fopen($file, "w");
$file_contents = str_replace(['0','1','2','3','4'],['1','2','3','4','5'],$file_contents);

fwrite($fh, $file_contents);
fclose($fh);

echo "New grades:\n";
echo $file_contents;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace it the other way around - from highest to lowest (instead of lowest to highest). This way you will replace 4 by 5, then there are no 4s - next, you replace 3 by 4, and so on - thus there are no overlaps.

```php
$file_contents = "1 2 3 4 5 4 5 2 1";
$result = str_replace(range(4, 0), range(5, 1), $file_contents);
echo $result;
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/hBB3R

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Still need to do some other fixes in my script, but that was main problem. I thought would just behave same way if changing numbers around.

Comment: It replaces sequentially - starts with the first element, then the next, and so on. It does not do it all at once.